# Change order in which data is drawn in d3

Tags: javascript, scala, d3.js, scala.js

I have some data (`Node`s) that I need to draw. These nodes can overlap and thus the **order** in which they are drawn is important (the ones supposed to be displayed on top need to be drawn lastly).

The position and consequently the z-axis of those nodes is subject to change, that is why I tried to model this behavior by using a *key*, that incoporates the current *index* of the List the nodes are stored in.

```scala
case class Node(id: Int)

def addNodesToSVG = {
   val sortedData: List[Node] = ??? 

   val nodesSelection = d3.select("#nodes").selectAll(".node")
      .data(sortedData.toJSArray, (n: Node) => {
         n.id.toString +
         // the position of those nodes may change over time
         // that's why we need to include the position in the identifier
         sortedData.indexOf(n)
   }

   nodesSelection.enter().append("g").attr("class", "node") // ...

   nodesSelection
       .attr("transform", transform) // ...

   nodesSelection.exit().remove()
}
```

Unfortunatly, this does not seem to work as expected.

In theory this is how I thought this is going to work if I just have two nodes (`n1` and `n2`), which are saved in a `List(n1, n2)`

```
node   key
-----  ---
n1      10 // node 1 at position 0
n2      21 // node 2 at position 1
```

Now if I change the List to `List(n2, n1)` and call `addNodesToSVG` again this is what I thought is going to happen:

```
node   key
-----  ---
n2      20 // node 1 at position 0
n1      12 // node 2 at position 1
```

Since these are unknown I thought it will remove (`nodesSelection.exit().remove()`) the old nodes and draw the 'new' ones in the correct order. This - however - is not happening. Why?

**Edit** after some more debugging I found out that my `exit` Selection is always of size 0.

Comment: `nodesSelection.append("g") // ...` what is this? Smells like inappropriate usage

Comment: Yes you are right; I did a mistake when copying my code to SO. Sorry about that, I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think id function should be used in a consistent manner -- just because an object changed its position, the result of the id's function on it shouldn't change (which as I see it is the whole point of using it in the first place). The approach I'd take would be making the id function to solely depend on node's id; add a field to data objects that specifies rendering order; sort selection after merging according to that new field.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="sw()">Switch</button>
  <script>
    var d1 = [{
      id: 'a',
      z: 1,
      fill: 'red', 
      y: 0
    }, {
      id: 'b',
      z: 2,
      fill: 'green', 
      y: 5
    }];
    
    var d2 = [{
      id: 'a',
      z: 2, 
      fill: 'red',
      y: 5
    }, {
      id: 'b',
      z: 1, 
      fill: 'green',
      y: 0
    }]
    
    var current = 0;
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
     .attr('viewBox', '0 0 10 20');

    function render(d) {
      var r = svg.selectAll('rect')
       .data(d, function(d) { return d.id; });
      r.enter()
       .append('rect')
       .attr('width', 10)
       .attr('height', 10)
       .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.fill; })
      .merge(r)
       .sort(function(r1, r2) {
         if (r1.z > r2.z) return 1;
         if (r1.z < r2.z) return -1;
         return 0;
       })
       .transition()
       .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y; });
      
      r.exit().remove();
    };
    
    function sw() {
        if (current == 0) {
          current = 1;
          render(d2);
        } else {
          current = 0;
          render(d1);
        }
    }
    
    render(d1);

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Although it seems a bit counterintuitive to store information on how to draw something (`z`) inside my data model this solution works for me. :) Thanks.

Comment: `.sort( (r1, r2) => r1.z - r2.z)`